# Apple MagicMouse randomly loses connection

Tags: connection, bluetooth, magic-mouse

My Magic Mouse periodically randomly loses connection to my macbook, sitting approximately a foot and a half away from it. There are no software updates available for Snow Leopard (10.6.3). I have a bluetooth keyboard (that sits a little closer to the macbook, though I'm not sure this is the issue) that rarely suffers from this problem.

Google results mostly suggest to update the software but I have the most updated version of it already.

Does anybody have any idea what could be causing the issue? Is this simply a defective mouse?

---

Additional info: I tried replacing the batteries with new ones, making sure they are sitting tightly in their position with no change in behavior (still disconnects periodically). Also, this doesn't seem to be a problem that the mouse is turning itself off to save battery - it does not reconnect when I move or click it. If I wait long enough (a couple of minutes) it reconnects on its own. Otherwise I have to go to the bluetooth menu with my macbook touchpad and choose "yuval's mouse -> Connect"

Comment: Do you have other wireless or bluetooth devices at home?  They might be interfering.

Comment: Are there any settings in MacOS to control the standby behavior of the ports you use for the mouse? I can imagine that the device simply goes into sleep mode or something like that.

Comment: Usual question: do the logs say anything? Look for them using Console.app

Answer (score 1):

I have this same problem with my magic mouse, except on my desktop.  When it quits, it never turns itself back on and I have no trackpad to use, of course.  I have to get my old magic mouse to use any of the functions I need to restore it.  If I turn the computer off, when I turn it back on it shows the mouse connection lost but that there's nothing to discover, even though the mouse is inches away and blinking in discovery mode.  What I've found that works is to turn both the mouse and computer off, then turn the mouse back on, then turn the computer back on.  If I turn the computer on first, it doesn't work-has to be the mouse on first.  It just seems like a glitch with the bluetooth.